# First recieved packet not displayed (Arduino with MRF24j40MA)

Tags: arduino-due

I'm trying to make two Arduino cards communicate, one is a sender and the other only receive packet from the first one and then display them.

My problem is that the first recieved packet is not displayed unlike the other packets(displayed normally)

here's the output of my code :

[image: serial monitor for both device]

Here's my code of the reciever :

```cpp
void handle_rx() {

Serial.print("received a packet ");Serial.print(mrf.get_rxinfo()->frame_length, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes long");

if(mrf.get_bufferPHY()){
  Serial.println("Packet data (PHY Payload):");
  for (int i = 0; i < mrf.get_rxinfo()->frame_length; i++) {
      Serial.print(mrf.get_rxbuf()[i]);
  }
}

Serial.println("\r\nASCII data (relevant data):");
for (int i = 0; i < mrf.rx_datalength(); i++) {
    Serial.write(mrf.get_rxinfo()->rx_data[i]);
}

Serial.print("\r\nLQI/RSSI=");
Serial.print(mrf.get_rxinfo()->lqi, DEC);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.println(mrf.get_rxinfo()->rssi, DEC);
}
```

Here is the complete sketch:

```cpp
/**
 * Example code for using a microchip mrf24j40 module to send and receive
 * packets using plain 802.15.4
 * Requirements: 3 pins for spi, 3 pins for reset, chip select and interrupt
 * notifications
 * This example file is considered to be in the public domain
 * Originally written by Karl Palsson, karlp@tweak.net.au, March 2011
 */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mrf24j.h>

const int pin_reset = 6;
const int pin_cs = 7; // default CS pin on ATmega8/168/328
const int pin_interrupt = 2; // default interrupt pin on ATmega8/168/328

Mrf24j mrf(pin_reset, pin_cs, pin_interrupt);

long last_time;
long last_time2;
long tx_interval = 1000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  mrf.reset();
  mrf.init();

  mrf.set_pan(0xcafe);
  // This is _our_ address
  mrf.address16_write(0x4201); 

  // uncomment if you want to receive any packet on this channel
  //mrf.set_promiscuous(true);

  // uncomment if you want to enable PA/LNA external control
  //mrf.set_palna(true);

  // uncomment if you want to buffer all PHY Payload
  //mrf.set_bufferPHY(true);

  attachInterrupt(0, interrupt_routine, CHANGE); // interrupt 0 equivalent to pin 2(INT0) on ATmega8/168/328
  last_time = millis();
  interrupts();
}

void interrupt_routine() {
    mrf.interrupt_handler(); // mrf24 object interrupt routine
}

void loop() {
    mrf.check_flags(&handle_rx, &handle_tx);
    unsigned long current_time = millis();
    if (current_time - last_time > tx_interval) {
        last_time = current_time;
        Serial.println("txxxing...");
        mrf.send16(0x4202, "abcd");
    }
}

void handle_rx() {
    Serial.print("received a packet ");Serial.print(mrf.get_rxinfo()->frame_length, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes long");

    if(mrf.get_bufferPHY()){
      Serial.println("Packet data (PHY Payload):");
      for (int i = 0; i < mrf.get_rxinfo()->frame_length; i++) {
          Serial.print(mrf.get_rxbuf()[i]);
      }
    }

    Serial.println("\r\nASCII data (relevant data):");
    for (int i = 0; i < mrf.rx_datalength(); i++) {
        Serial.write(mrf.get_rxinfo()->rx_data[i]);
    }

    Serial.print("\r\nLQI/RSSI=");
    Serial.print(mrf.get_rxinfo()->lqi, DEC);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.println(mrf.get_rxinfo()->rssi, DEC);
}

void handle_tx() {
    if (mrf.get_txinfo()->tx_ok) {
        Serial.println("TX went ok, got ack");
    } else {
        Serial.print("TX failed after ");Serial.print(mrf.get_txinfo()->retries);Serial.println(" retries\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. It looks like there may be some parts missing from it.  Try reading this: http://snippets-r-us.com/